# Having trouble in adding nodes in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hello, I'm having trouble adding nodes to my firebase database.
I have created this tree where the first node is `orderId`, the second is `userId` and I want to add a date like in the picture but I'm having trouble adding it. I'm using firebase database.

Here's my code:

```
public void addToDatabase(String userId){

    //create a unique key for the order
    String orderId = ordersReference.push().getKey();

    ordersReference = ordersReference.child(orderId).child(userId);


    for(CheckOut g: GroceryActivity.list){

        String name = g.getName();
        String orderQuantity = g.getQuantity();
        Order order = new Order(name , orderQuantity);

        ordersReference.child(name).setValue(order);

    }

}//end addToDatabase method
```

Comment: what is the trouble you are having

Comment: adding the date like in the picture

Comment: So you only need to add a new property `date: "25/3/2020"` under banana? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i want to add date property under the orderId which is -M3G_ot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> I want to add date property under the `orderId` which is -M3G_ot...

All you have to do is to use the [updateChildren()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method:

> Update the specific child keys to the specified values. Passing null in a map to updateChildren() will remove the value at the specified location.

Assuming that `orderId` holds the value of `M3G_ ... 1Ay2`, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference orderIdRef = ordersReference.child(orderId);
Map<String, Object> dateUpdate = new HashMap<>();
dateUpdate.put("date", "25/3/2020");
orderIdRef.updateChildren(dateUpdate);
```